# I am trying to learn Objective C but maybe my enviroment is wrong?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  printf("Hello World!!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I have a MacAir running OS X 10.6.1 with XCode version 3.2.1.  When I attempt to compile the lines above I get 3951 errors.  Most of them seem to be NSObjCRunntime.h file where NSString is defined.  When I comment out `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` I get no errors.  Is there something wrong in my setup?

Thanks

Comment: What sort of XCode project did you specify?

Comment: Are you doing this in XCode?  If not, what command line are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're compiling this as C, so the Objective-C in Foundation is freaking it out. How are you compiling this? What sort of project is it? Is the file called `main.c` (which is a C file) or `main.m` (which is an Objective-C file)?

Comment: While technically true, you can compile .c files as Objective-C by getting the files info (in Xcode) and changing the file type (in the General tab) from `sourcecode.c` to `sourcecode.c.objc`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not linking in the Foundation framework.  Check out the "Like binary with libraries" phase of your target, and make sure that Foundation.framework is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you link against the specified SDK and framework:

```
gcc -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk  -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation ...
```

Replace as needed for your version of the SDK and your frameworks.